# Vite/Vue3 : Sometimes the url changes after router.push() runs, but the related component is not rendered

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I'm developing a project using Vue3 and Vite. Sometimes the url changes after router.push() runs, but the related component is not rendered.I struggled a lot with this problem, but I could not get a result. As a last resort, I wanted to explain my problem here and get help. RouteName is an enum and it stores the route names as strings. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Library versions;

vue: ^3.2.45
vue-router: ^4.1.6
vite: ^4.0.0

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  envDir: './env',
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/locales/**')
    })
  ],
  build: {
    sourcemap: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['flatpickr/dist/types']
  }
})
```

router.ts

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 

'vue-router'
import { CheckAuthType, RouteName } from '../types/enums/system'

import loggedInRoutes from './LoggedIn/loggedInRoutes'

const Error404 = () => import('../views/Error/Error404.vue')
const Login = () => import('../views/Auth/Login.vue')
const RegisteredHome = () => import('../views/Home/RegisteredHome.vue')

import { SessionManager } from '../managers'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    name: RouteName.error404,
    component: Error404
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: (to) => {
      console.log('TEST ROOT REDIRECT TO: ', to.name)

      return { name: RouteName.login }
    }
  },
  {
    name: RouteName.login,
    path: '/login',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const sessionExist = SessionManager.sessionExist()

      console.log(`TEST BEFORE ENTER LOGIN TO: ${to.name as string} FROM: ${from.name as string} SESSION: ${sessionExist}`)
      if (sessionExist) {
        next({
          name: RouteName.dashboard
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dsh',
    component: RegisteredHome,
    props: {
      main: true
    },
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true
    },
    name: RouteName.registeredHome,
    children: loggedInRoutes
  }
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition || { left: 0, top: 0 }
  }
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const sessionExist = SessionManager.sessionExist()
  console.log(`TEST BEFORE EACH TO: ${to.name as string} FROM: ${from.name as string} SESSION: ${sessionExist}`)

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requireAuth)) {
    if (!sessionExist) {
      next({
        name: RouteName.login
      })
    } else {
      if (to.meta.authKey) {
        if (Array.isArray(to.meta.authKey) && to.meta.authKey.length) {
          let checkCount = 0

          to.meta.authKey.forEach((key) => {
            if (SessionManager.checkAuth(key)) {
              checkCount++
            }
          })

          if (to.meta.checkAuthType === CheckAuthType.EVERY) {
            if (checkCount === to.meta.authKey.length) {
              next()
            } else {
              next({
                name: RouteName.unauthorized
              })
            }
          } else {
            if (checkCount > 0) {
              next()
            } else {
              next({
                name: RouteName.unauthorized
              })
            }
          }
        } else if (SessionManager.checkAuth(to.meta.authKey as string)) {
          next()
        } else {
          next({
            name: RouteName.unauthorized
          })
        }
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

router.afterEach((to, from, failure) => {
  if (failure) {
    console.log('ROUTE ISSUE!', failure)
  }
})

export default router
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

import App from './App.vue'

import '../src/assets/css/app.css'
import Toast from 'vue-toastification'
import { LocalizationManager } from './managers'
import { vMaska } from 'maska'
import moment from 'moment-timezone'
import { BreadCrumbItem } from './types/classes/system'
import 'vue-router'
import { CheckAuthType } from './types/enums/system'
import 'leaflet'
declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    authKey?: Array<string> | string
    checkAuthType?: CheckAuthType
    activeMenu?: string
    breadCrumb?: Array<BreadCrumbItem>
  }
}

declare module 'leaflet' {
  interface MarkerOptions {
    locationIndex?: number
  }
}

moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Istanbul')

const app = createApp(App).use(router)

app.use(Toast)
app.use(LocalizationManager.i18n.value)
app.directive('maska', vMaska)
app.mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
  <LoadingOverlay />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { EventManager, LocalizationManager, SessionManager } from './managers'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import LoadingOverlay from './components/LoadingOverlay.vue'
import { watch, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { EventName, RouteName } from './types/enums/system'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
const { t } = useI18n()
LocalizationManager.changeTitle()

const logoutAndGotoMain = () => {
  router.push({ name: RouteName.login })
}

const changeTitle = () => {
  const projectName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PROJECT_NAME
  let pageName = route.name
  let temp = projectName
  if (pageName) {
    temp += ' | ' + t('PageNames.' + pageName.toString())
  }
  document.title = temp
}

watch(
  () => route.name,
  () => {
    changeTitle()
  }
)

if (import.meta.env.VITE_APP_DEBUG_SCREEN as boolean) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('debug-screens')
}

onMounted(() => {
  EventManager.emitter.on(EventName.logoutAndGotoMain, logoutAndGotoMain)
  EventManager.emitter.on(EventName.changeTitle, changeTitle)
  if (SessionManager.sessionToken) {
    SessionManager.refreshSession()
  }
})
</script>
```

RegisteredHome.vue

```
<template>
  <SideMenu>
    <div class="pt-6">
      <router-view name="loggedIn"></router-view>
    </div>
  </SideMenu>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import SideMenu from '@/layout/SideMenu.vue'
</script>
```

LoggedInRoutes.ts

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import { RouteName } from '@/types/enums/system'

import DashboardRoutes from './DashboardRoutes'
import SystemRoutes from './System'

const Unauthorized = () => import('@/views/Error/Unauthorized.vue')

const loggedInRoutes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/unauthorized',
    name: RouteName.unauthorized,
    components: {
      loggedIn: Unauthorized
    },
    meta: {
      breadCrumb: [
        {
          routeName: RouteName.unauthorized,
          active: true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...DashboardRoutes,
  ...SystemRoutes,
]

export default loggedInRoutes
```

I tried adding `<router-view>` :key but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide you code as text, not images. Otherwise your question will be banned. Also you could provide a working sandbox project with your code so anybody would debug your live version. Otherwise recreating your project could be painful, thanks

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I did not encounter any errors related to the subject in the console. I tried to catch the error with the router.afterEach() function, but still there is no error in the console. I rarely encounter this error and I cannot explain the situation when the url changes after pressing the button while making a presentation and the page does not open.